# Передать параметр в SQL CMD в Bat файле

Tags: sql, windows, cmd

Можете, пожалуйста подсказать, как задать переменную в бат файле и использовать ее как аргумент в SQL CMD? Вот тут нужно, чтоб подхватился dbname.

```
set dbname = DESKTOP-11 

sqlcmd -S $(dbname)-U sa -P pass  -i "G:\CMDtest\script_1.sql"

pause >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlcmd -S $(%dbname%) -U sa -P pass  -i "G:\CMDtest\script_1.sql"
```

Comment: Ругается на подключение. Код такой: set dbname = "DESKTOP-11" 

sqlcmd -S $(%dbname%) -U sa -P 1111  -i "G:\CMDtest\script_1.sql"